# How to start a macro with a Button in Outlook Form?

Tags: vba, forms, outlook

I have a user defined form in Outlook 2019.

How can I start a macro by pressing a button in the form?

The macro is in *ThisOutlookSession*.
It sets the cursor at the end of the body of the form:

```vb
Public Sub SetCursor()
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Dim Range As Word.Range
    Dim Pos As Long
    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set Doc = Ins.WordEditor
    If Not Doc Is Nothing Then
        Pos = Doc.Range.End - 1
        Set Range = Doc.Range(Pos, Pos)
        Range.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

The code to start the macro is in the *Outlook Form*:

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CODE TO CALL THE MACRO NEEDED!?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Hide
    SetCursor
End Sub
```